# How to convert SKOS format to other formats such as RDF/XML, Turtle, etc

Tags: rdf, ontology, skos

I have Ontology in SKOS format which was developed using Smartlogic. I want to convert this into different formats such as Turtle, RDF/XML, etc.

I know that we can use Apache Jena to convert one version of an ontology to another. Is there some library in JAVA which can be used to convert SKOS (Simple Knowledge Organization System) to RDF/XML?

Comment: SKOS is an RDF vocabulary. There's no "SKOS format" that I'm aware of.  A "SKOS format" file is already in RDF, and any RDF processing library should be able to convert it into other RDF serialization formats.  If you have some "SKOS file" that's not in RDF already, you'll need to show an example, or else we have no idea what you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Semaphore Workbench, edit your model and choose Model > Export.  This will create a text serialization file in Turtle, N-Triples, or RDF/XML that you can use external to Smartlogic.

Answer (score 1):

RDF Translator is a multi-format conversion tool for structured markup. It provides translations between data formats ranging from RDF/XML to RDFa or Microdata. The service allows for conversions triggered either by URI or by direct text input. Furthermore it comes with a straightforward REST API for developers.

http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/